# Modus ponens rule

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms

Prove for the calculus of propositions:
$$
A\rightarrow B\mapsto(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)
$$
I had used axioms and most suitable was this one:
$$
X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow(X\rightarrow(Y\rightarrow Z)\rightarrow(X\rightarrow Z))
$$
(axiom2). Then I used Modus ponens rule and got this result:
$$
A\rightarrow B,\ A\rightarrow B\rightarrow (A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))\\
A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)
$$

Then I didn't understand, how to get $(B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$. What axiom should I use or rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *Deduction Theorem*:

1. $A \to B$ --- premise
2. $B \to C$ --- assumed [a]
3. $(B \to C) \to (A \to (B \to C))$ --- Ax.1
4. $A \to (B \to C)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *Modus Ponens*
5. $(A \to B) \to ((A \to (B \to C)) \to (A \to C))$ --- Ax.2
6. $((A \to (B \to C)) \to (A \to C))$ --- from 1) and 5) by *Modus Ponens*
7. $A \to C$ --- from 4) and 6) by *Modus Ponens*.

> 8. $(B \to C) \to (A \to C)$ --- from 2) and 7) by *DT*, discharging assumption [a]

Comment: i have a question: could we use Deduction Theorem for this one:$A→B,B→C↦A→C$?

Comment: @sjr_25 - YES. Modify the above proof assuming also $A$, followed by MP twice to get $C$ and then conclude by DT with $A \to C$.

Comment: Can I ask another question on this topic?

Comment: @sjr_25 - why not ?

Comment: Can i rewrite this ¬ A,¬ B→(¬ AVB)→(AV¬B) like A⟷B

Comment: @sjr_25 - $A⟷B$ is $(A→B) \land (B→A)$ that is equiv to $(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot B \lor A)$

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it  $¬A,¬ B↦(¬ A∨B)→(A∨¬B)$?

Comment: @sjr_25 - ask a new question...

Comment: Basically, from $\lnot B$ you can derive $(\lnot B \lor A)$ using [Addition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)